# Authlib - passing authorize url as json

Tags: flask, authlib

I'm building a SPA using Flask as an api and Vue js as front end. I'm using Authlib for user authentication and planning to use Facebook OAuth. I've already tried [the example](https://github.com/authlib/demo-oauth-client) with Facebook and it's working. But I want to build this in a RESTful way. What I'm trying to do is change this part from app.py from the example:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('auth', _external=True)
    return oauth.google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
```

to a json.

Is there a method in the library to get the url of Facebook dialog so that I can pass that as json and do the redirection in Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to return a url value in the JSON response?

```
resp = oauth.google.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
url = resp.location
return jsonify(url=url)
```

Like the above code?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks for this library too.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/facebook.html):

```
>>> import requests_oauthlib
>>> from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
>>> from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import facebook_compliance_fix
>>> facebook = OAuth2Session(client_id='test', redirect_uri='https://test.me')
>>> facebook = facebook_compliance_fix(facebook)
>>> authorization_url, state = facebook.authorization_url('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth')
>>> authorization_url
'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.me&state=bfipsir5GsKc1CbdPZCgBT0jIn2eq6'
```